# MS Access sorting one column and moving the other

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have been working on MS Access these days with C#.Is there any way I can sort one column's numbers with moving the exact same line things from other columns?For example [Ms access board screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtEdI.png)

Since 31 is lower than 35 and greater than 30,can I move Peter with the score 31 between John 30 and Jessica 35.

Comment: I assume you are just trying to change the order in which the rows are displayed? If not, then what is Field2 all about? There must be some direct relationship? i.e. Field2 could be the Age of the people listed in Field1? Then if you want to list people by age, sort on 'Field2'; to kist by name, sort on Field1. If you're trying to do something else, please explain.

Comment: Yes,there are people with their ages.I want to sort ages but not to mess up with their names.Every person must have the same age it had before.

Comment: Since you were showing the content of a table, unless you change the actual data, you can sort, or present it any way you want using a query or form or report. I suggest just using a query to select and sort.

Comment: Well,I'm trying to sort them because I want to make something like a TOP 10 (the youngest ones) list while I keep adding names and ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting rows in a database table will always move entire rows, leaving the fields in place. In a database it is actually very hard to impossible to tear rows apart while sorting, even if you want to.

That means that you can just apply the sorting mechanism provided by the database abstraction layer you use. If you use SQL directly, just append `ORDER BY Field2` at the end.